# Como darle formato numérico a una variable en php

Tags: php

Buenas tardes. sucede que tengo una variable con un numero que se a generado de una suma, lo que quisiera es darle formato para que me muestre los puntos de miles y se vea reflejado en un input, tengo este codigo pero no hace nada.

```
number_format($total);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes probar con `echo number_format($total, 2, ',', '.');`

Donde:

- **2** Indica el número de decimales a mostrar
- **','** Indica el separador que se va a usar para el separador de los decimales
- **'.'** Indica el separador que se va a usar para el separador de los miles

Comment: gracias a todos

Answer (score 3):

Desde el manual de [PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php)

number_format
(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)

**number_format** — Formatear un número con los millares agrupados

**Descripción**
string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] )
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )
Esta función acepta uno, dos, o cuatro parámetros (no tres):

Si solo se proporciona un parámetro, number será formateado sin decimales, pero con una coma (",") entre cada grupo de millares.

Si se proporcionan dos parámetros, number será formateado con tantos decimales como se hayan definido en decimals colocando un punto (".") delante, y una coma (",") entre cada grupo de millares.

Si se proporcionan los cuatro parámetros, number será formateado con tantos decimales como hayamos definido en decimals, dec_point sustituirá al punto (".") como seperador de los decimales y el separador por defecto de los millares, la coma (","), será sustituida por thousands_sep.

**Parámetros**
number
El número al que dar formato.

**decimals**
Establece el número de puntos decimales.

**dec_point**
Establece el separador para los decimales.

**thousands_sep**
Establece el separador para los millares.

**Valores devueltos** 
Una versión formateada de number.

Algunos ejemplos

```
<?php

$número = 1234.56;

// notación inglesa (por defecto)
$número_formato_inglés = number_format($número);
// 1,235

// notación francesa
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($número, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$número = 1234.5678;

// notación inglesa sin separador de millares
$english_format_number = number_format($número, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[php number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php)

```
$total = 5000;
echo number_format((int)$total,0,'','.');
```

si quieres con 2 decimales al final

```
$total = 5000;
echo number_format((int)$total,2,',','.');
```