# Menejo de moneda en Laravel

Tags: mysql, float

mi duda es la siguiente, empece un proyecto que maneja dinero y el campo lo cree como FLOAT esto entiendo que fue un error debido a que no me respeta los puntos y decimales. Por ejemplo si guardo 10.000 en la base de datos me guarda 10.00 y al obtener estos datos en la vista me muestra 10.
¿Como sería la manera apropiada? en mi opinión me gustaría manejarlos como string pero no sé si en un futuro para realizar calculos sea recomendado.

¿Me pueden brindar sus opiniones? gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: ¿`10.000` son diez con cero céntimos o diez mil? Si son diez mil, simplemente no uses punto en tu publicación, pues la hace confusa, ya que el punto es el separador decimal en USA y muchos países y suele ser el separador decimal por convención en los lenguajes de programación.

Comment: Hola @BetaM utilizo Mysql. ahora agregué number_format y me separa los datos pero por ejemplo guarde 25.000 y con en la base me puso 25.00. Conviene cambiar FLOAT a STRING?

Comment: Hola @jachguate voy a probar sin agregar el . suena que ese era el problema.

Comment: El problema no es como almacenarlos, sino como vas a visualizarlo... quieres cargar un problema en la base de datos pudiendo darle solución desde las mismas vistas. esta bien que trabajes con el tipo de dato float, te va ayudar a hacer todos los calculas que necesitas... Ahora si quieres visualizarlo solo necesitas pasar los datos por algún método que cambie SOLO su apariencia, PERO NO EL DATO EN SI

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como darle formato numérico a una variable en php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126407/como-darle-formato-num%c3%a9rico-a-una-variable-en-php)

Comment: @BetaM muchas gracias! exacto lo que necesitaba!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilice number_format y con el tipo de dato FLOAT funciona como lo necesito. Muchas gracias @jachguate.

La función la agregué en blade indicando en la variable $propiedades->precio el valor flota, con el 2 los decimales a mostrar y en lo string que muestre primero el punto y después la coma.

Generando:

```
$propiedades->precio = 25000

{{ number_format($propiedades->precio, 2, ",", ".") }}
```

Resultado:

```
 25.000.00
```